# How can I prevent moire patterns with my procedural weave texture

Tags: procedural

I have managed to create a weave like procedural pattern, that looks OK close up. I see nice bumps left-right and up-down with the different colors of the fabric threads (still working on the little 'spikes' by the way :) ).
[image]

However, when zooming out, the material experiences heavy Moiré patterns
[image]

What would be the strategy to prevent the Moiré from happening?

My ultimate goal is to have the 'left-to-right' thread color be picked from a color ramp with some 'constant' stops for the repeating horizontal color bands, and the 'top-to-bottom' thread from another color ramp for the vertical color bands, thus creating fabric patterns as seen on tablecloths, like this:
[image]

Up close the real fabric looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can lower this effect by increasing the number of samples here:

[image]

For viewport rendering, if you are using Cycles, switch to Eevee to modify the viewport samples (and eventually switch back to Cycles after that).

You should not have the same issue using Cycles.